# How To Send 20mb Video To Cross-Domain Site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, post, video, cross-domain

I'm trying to send a video to a cross domain site using standard Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://site2.com/RecordVideo.aspx?user=U&video=V, 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: "json", 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    data : '{""}', 
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("It Works!!");
    }, 
    error: function() {
        console.log('duuh!.');
    } 
});
```

And in the page load, I receive the post data and store it.

But, the sending data is not Working...None of the videos are lower than 20mb, so  it does not work because of the size of the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

McBride,

If you were not sending this in a cross domain situation, you should have to use `Jsonp`.

But, if you trying to send a 20mb video, this request crashes. I don't know the reason it happens.

I had the same problem and I used `$.post` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Here's an example:

```
$.post(
      "http://site2.com/RecordVideo.aspx",
      { user : U, video : V},
function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

Do you have a cross domain request and are you using this ASPX page as a proxy page ?
How do you get the data and store ?